# Is it possible to share behavior with controllers in ember through inheritance instead of using 'needs'

Tags: ember.js

Below I have provided an example of what I 'think' should work, but does not. My expectation is that if a controller inherits from another controller, than it should be able to access provided behaviors in the parent class. I know that the same behavior can be achieved with 'needs', but I think it would be much cleaner if you could inherit behavior.

https://gist.github.com/4589210

Answer (score 5):

You can alternatively use `mixin`. What it is? It is kind of multi inheritance.

```
App.Important = Ember.Mixin.create({
  sharedBehavior: function() {
    return "A winner is you!!!";
  }.property()
});

App.OtherImportant = Ember.Mixin.create({
  otherSharedBehavior: function() {
    return "A winner is not you!!!";
  }.property()
});

App.AnotherController = Ember.controller.extend(App.Important, App.OtherImportant, {
  importantStuff: function() {
    var ohBeehave = this.get("sharedBehavior");
    if(ohBeehave) { 
      return ohBeehave;
    } else {
      return "FML";
    }
  }.property("sharedBehavior")
});
```

See http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Mixin.html

Comment: That's better solution if you're using Ember-CLI.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that controllers should be able to inherit properties from other controllers. Here is a working example based on your gist:

http://jsbin.com/uzeyum/1/edit

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  sharedBehavior: function() {
    return "A winner is you!!!";
  }.property()
});


App.AnotherController = App.ApplicationController.extend({
  importantStuff: function() {
    var ohBeehave = this.get("sharedBehavior");
    if(ohBeehave) { 
      return ohBeehave;
    } else {
      return "FML";
    }
  }.property("sharedBehavior")
});
```

That said, from experience I can tell you that inheritance is very rarely what you want. There are many reasons for this, see [Prefer composition over inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance) for detail.

By declaring an array of dependencies via the `needs` property rather than inheritance you will find over time that your application is less brittle and easier to test/change.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback on the problem. I am not seeing this working in ember 1.0.0-pre4. When it comes to inheritance over composition, I think we are talking about opinion here.

Comment: Of course, it's all opinion :-) Part of using an opinionated framework like ember is being aware of those opinions, and for sure inheritance over composition is one of them. If you know what you are doing and decide to go against the grain that's cool, just want to be sure anyone reading this in future is aware. Re: inheritance not working in 1.0.0-pre4, that's the ember version i used in the above jsbin and worked fine there. Perhaps there is something else going on, can you post a jsbin showing the failure?

Comment: Michael - I got the solution working, the error was a byproduct of another error. I am more than comfortable going against the grain in this case ;) I drink *most* of the kool-aid.